# Capitalizing Every Other Letter Using Assigned Variables

Tags: python, variables, capitalization

So I have an assignment I have to do and I'm stuck with one thing. I have a string named

```
MeRcUrY
```

I needed to somehow assign variables to each character and capitalize on the lowercases and uncapitalize the uppercases using variables. I already assigned the lowercases 1s and uppercases 0s. Now how do I capitalize and uncapitalize 0? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 0s and 1s? Please be more specific, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is going to be to do a comprehension over the string so you can uppercase/lowercase each character in turn:

```
>>> ''.join(c.upper() if c.islower() else c.lower() for c in "MeRcUrY")
'mErCuRy'
```

In this comprehension, the variable `c` is being assigned to each character in turn.  The resulting iterable of modified characters (strings) is turned back into a single string via the `join` function.

Typically if you're doing something across an entire string or list, it's not necessary to assign a separate named variable to each element; instead you want to do an iteration where the variable's value automatically changes to refer to each value one by one so that you can do the same thing to each one with a single block of code.